# Code stops execution without throwing error

Tags: javascript, debugging, dom

I am trying to implement Conway's game of life using checkboxes. In theory I should start with some checkbox checked randomly (and possibly some other manually checked by the user) and then go to the next generation by hitting a button. The code I made so far starts with just unchecked checkboxes (the random part is a detail I will care about later).

Here's my code:

```js
function createBoard( rows = 30, columns = 50 ) {
    let board = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(board);
    for(let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        let row = document.createElement('div');
        for(let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.className = "cb";
            row.appendChild(checkbox);
        }
        board.appendChild(row);
    }
}

function nextGen( rows = 30, columns = 50 ) {
    function neighbourhood( r, c ) {
        let sum = 0;
        for( let i = -1; i < 2; i++ ) {
            for( let j = -1; j < 2; j++ ) {
                if( r + i >= 0 && c + j >= 0 && r + i < rows && c + j < columns && (i || j) ) {
                    sum += current[r+i][c+j];
                }
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
    let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.cb');
    const flatBoard = Array.prototype.map.call(checkboxes, cb => cb.checked);
    let current = flatBoard.reduce((cur, cb, i) => (!(i%columns) ? cur.push([cb]) : cur[cur.length-1].push(cb)) && cur, []);
    let counter = 0;
    console.log("ONE");
    for(let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            console.log("TWO");
            const sum = neighbourhood(i,j);
            checkboxes[counter++].checked = sum == 3 || current[i][j] && sum == 2;
        }
    }
}

createBoard();

let nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextGen, false);
```

```html
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Does anyone know why when you hit the button, the first `console.log()` is being executed while the second is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextGen` is called with an argument that is determined by the DOM API: the event object. This will be the first argument and set the parameter variable `rows`. This means the `for` condition on `rows` will be false and so you have no iterations of the outer `for` loop.

To fix this particular problem, make sure that `nextGen` is called without any arguments:

```
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => nextGen(), false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I will accept the answer as soon as I am allowed to.